# ¿Por què la API de Google Maps, no me trae mi ubicaciòn?

Tags: api

tengo el problema que cuando quiero integrar la parte de Geolocalización a mi mapa no me aparece nada en pantalla. Empecé con los marcadores desde un archivo XML y hasta ahì todo perfecto. Ahora quiero poner que detecte la localizaciòn del dispositivo no me trae nada de nada y no encuentro el error.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Paradas de colectivos</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
   
  <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      function initMap() {
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
              center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
              zoom: 14
            });
 
       var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
```

Comment: Has puesto la referencia a HTML5 al principio del documento? es decir el doctype html?
...

Comment: Ahí editè la publicación para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: intenta agregando width: <div id="map" style="width: 500px"></div>

Comment: Los navegadores necesitan autorización para obtener tu ubicación, puede ser por aqui el problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ahora quiero poner que detecte la localizaciòn del dispositivo no me trae nada de nada y no encuentro el error.

Si tu sitio carece de **HTTPS**, consigue uno y verás que funciona.

Sucede que la siguiente línea:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

Se ejecuta únicamente en contextos seguros (HTTPS).

Referencia:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition#Browser_compatibility

Ahora bien, para probar esto, puedes levantar un servidor con su respectivo certificado, vamos a hacer uso de https://education.github.com/pack que genera **$50 in platform credit for new users**

Ahora bien, usando Let's Encrypt tenemos el SSL gratuito, si tienes nginx como webserver, el siguiente enlace te caerá bien:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Y si tienes un apache, aquí vamos con todo el power 2.0!!

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo!

Comment: de nada hermano, actualicé mi respuesta para que sea de mayor utilidad, éxitos en todo :D